# Oracle as our new ERP solution

Tags: oracle

Our company just decided on Oracle as our new ERP solution. As the current in-house Developer of our WMS/ERP system (VB6/C#/ SQL/VFP) What skills, references, things to learn, words of wisdom you recommend to get a head of the curve for this supplementation.

Answer (score 2):

By "Oracle is our new ERP system" do you mean you are migrating your custom code to an Oracle-database based system?

If that's the case, [Oracle Database concepts guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/toc.htm) is probably the first thing that you should get started with. There is obviously a big learning curve to this and it will take time, but as someone who understands the existing system, you are definitely at an advantage.

If you mean you are moving to a vendor based (oracle being the vendor) ERP system, there are many systems out there that Oracle has released into the market and each of them with a different technology framework and underlying components. Eg..If you are moving on to Oracle Apps 11i modules or E-Biz, Java and Oracle Database would be the underlying components that you need to concentrate on first. If the ERP system is the new [Fusion Applications](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/fusion/index.html) suite, [Oracle's ADF Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index.html) is the place to begin.

By the way, any specific reason why they have such a HUGE shift in the technology stack?

Comment: Thanks again for the timely response. Let me start by answering your question. We are taking this HUGE night and day step because for the past six years we have grown to capacity on our current system. The company is also at the point where strong growth is in the foreseeable future. Our previous software selection (10 years ago) left our company running a split system. We have have to deal with the headaches of our business functions not tied to our IC/QA/WMS. As big of a jump this move is to Orcale I believe this will benefits everyone in the company work-flow and processes.